# How to pass a value from the view to a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to get the Id to filter items to show.
After several tutorials and docs, I'm still not get through...

Is it possible to do it ?

Here is the form:

```
class MakeChecklistDone(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakeChecklistDone, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #title = forms.CharField(max_length = 32)
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
                    queryset=CheckUpList.objects.all().filter(done=False, task=???)
                    )
    class Meta:
        model = CheckUpList
        fields = ['choices', ]
```

I'm using the bellow view :

```
def task_detail(request, pk):
    template_name = 'task/task-detail.html'
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    else:
    form_checkUpList = MakeChecklistDone(request.POST, initial={'task': 11 })
```

But it seems I'm doing something wrong...
Any helps will be marvellous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, Thanks Salma. I made a confusion between "CBV" and "View function".

```
def task_detail(request, pk):
    template_name = 'task/task-detail.html'
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ..
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    else:
    form_checkUpList = MakeChecklistDone(task=task, request.POST)
```

For the form:

```
class MakeChecklistDone(forms.ModelForm):
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=None)
    class Meta:
        model = CheckUpList
        fields = ['choices', ]

    def __init__(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakeChecklistDone, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choices'].queryset = CheckUpList.objects.all().filter(done=False, task=task))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a view function using a view class (Create view, update view, listing v) and use the get_form_kwargs method to pass a value to the form like below:

```
class task_detail(LoginRequiredMixin,
                     UpdateView):
    template_name = 'learningcenters/lc/form.html'
    form_class = LearningCenterForm
    queryset = CheckUpList.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return get_object_or_404(task_detail, id=id_)


    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['task'] = 11
        return kwargs
```

In form in init:

```
    def __init__(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakeChecklistDone, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
                    queryset=CheckUpList.objects.all().filter(done=False, task=task)
                    )
```